# Peer relationships measurement

Tags: social-psychology, measurement, psychology

Is there a method for measuring peer relationships in university students (e.g., a questionnaire)?

I am looking for a questionnaire that can be used to asses the level of peer relationship among students. In other words, how students are able to relate to their peers.

Comment: Hmmmm.... Now that I've posted my answer I'm not sure this is what you looking for. Are simply after a questionnaire that determines how A relates to B? Or is the unit of analysis a group of students?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This field of research is known as **social network analysis**, or *SNA*. It existed well before Facebook et al. hijacked the term.

Various resources will include sample questionnaires and the mathematical analysis applied ([Networks: An Introduction](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Networks-Introduction-Mark-Newman/dp/0199206651/) was for me by far the clearest text on the mathematics of networks; a lot of books on SNA are off-putting once you get to the maths part).

You may also want to google for graph databases (eg, neo4j). I'm pretty sure I've seen a few examples of such analysis floating about.